SQL Server: Querying Change Data Tables directly?
I am messing around with Change Data Capture on SQL Server.
Documentation for table containing the change data (cdc.<capture_instance>_CT) says:

We recommend that you do not query the system tables directly. Instead, execute the cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_<capture_instance> and cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_<capture_instance> functions.

However, it neglect to mention reason for such recommendation. My tests suggests that querying the table directly is cca 2* faster, so I lean towards skipping the recommended functions. Is that safe/reasonable? Or am I missing something important?
